# Using Python to find LUKS passphrase

Tags: python, encryption

I have an encrypted volume for which I can almost, but not quite, remember the password.

There are 10 characters that I am uncertain of: some are casing, some letter vs number, and possibly being omitted completely.

I can have python print a list of all the possible passwords, but how can I have it also test them to determine the correct answer rather than going down the list typing them myself?

Example of what I've got so far- let's say the passphrase is some play on "the_pass"

```
passparts = [["t", "T"], ["h"], ["e", "3"], ["_", ""], ["p"], ["a", "4"], ["s"], ["s"]]
possibilities = itertools.product(*passparts)
for x in possibilities:
    possible = "".join(x)
    print possible
```

Is it possible to have python test 'possible' each time to see if it can decrypt the volume?

also my real world problem has 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*3 = 1536 possibilities, I assume python can test each one fast enough that this wouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did a poor job of explaining the problem, but I solved it and am posting the answer here in case anyone else happens across this.

So, I found you could easily start and interact with a terminal process using pexpect which you will need to download. anyway, this worked for me:

```
passparts = [["t", "T"], ["h"], ["e", "3"], ["_", ""], ["p"], ["a", "4"], ["s"], ["s"]]
possibilities = itertools.product(*passparts)
for x in possibilities:
    possible = "".join(x)
    print possible
    child = pexpect.spawn('udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdc2')
    child.logfile = open("/tmp/mylog", "w")
    child.expect(".*")
    child.sendline(possible)
    child.expect(".*")
    print(child.before)
    child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)
    print child.before
    print child.after
```

not a very fast method, but it found my correct passphrase in less than 10minutes.